# How do I encrypt for multiple recipients using RSA in window.crypto.subtle?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa, subtlecrypto

I need to use window.crypto.subtle.encrypt() to encrypt for multiple recipient public keys.

This is my code right now:

```js
        const encryptedMessage = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            rsaOptions,
            participantKeys[0],
            enc.encode(message)
        );
```

`participantKeys` in this scenario is an array of public keys, and at the moment this is only encrypting for the first public key in the array. I need to encrypt for *all* public keys in the array.

I tried giving the encrypt() function the whole array, but it did not work for me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just loop over the array?

Comment: Use hybrid encryption. Encrypt the data using a random AES key and then encrypt the AES key for each user. Just looks and similar systems like GnuPG, S/MIME; EFS, ...

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have done that as a temporary solution, however it's not very efficient.

Comment: @Robert Does this design allow for perfect forward secrecy?